# Import file from a folder based on a regular expression

Tags: stata

I am working with DHS data, which involves various data files with a consistent naming located in different folders. Each folder contains data for a specific country and survey year.

I would like to import datasets whose name consists of the component 'HR' for example I have `ETHR41FL.DTA`. The 'HR' part is consistent but other components of the name vary depending on country and survey year. I need to work with one dataset at a time and then move to the next so I believe an automated search would be helpful.

Running the command below gives:

```
dir "*.dta"

  42.6M   5/17/07 10:49  ETBR41FL.dta      
  19.4M   7/17/06 12:32  ETHR41FL.DTA      
  60.5M   7/17/06 12:33  ETIR41FL.DTA      
  10.6M   7/17/06 12:33  ETKR41FL.DTA      
 234.4k   4/05/07 12:36  ETWI41FL.DTA
```

I have tried the following approach which did not go through as desired and might not be the best or most direct approach:

```
local datafiles : dir . files  "*.dta" //store file names in a macro
di `datafiles'
etbr41fl.dtaethr41fl.dtaetir41fl.dtaetkr41fl.dtaetwi41fl.dta
```

The next step I think would be to store the value of the macro `datafiles` above into a variable (since `strupper` does not seem to work with macros but variables) and then convert to uppercase and extract the string `ETHR41FL.dta`. However, I encounter a problem when I do this:

```
local datafiles : dir . files  "*.dta" //store file names in a macro

gen datafiles= `datafiles'
invalid '"ethr41fl.dta'
```

If I try the command below it works but gives a variable of empty values:

```
local datafiles : dir . files  "*.dta" //store file names in a macro

gen datafiles= "`datafiles'"
```

How can I store the components of `datafiles` into a new variable?

If this works I could then extract the required string using a regular expression and import the dataset:

```
gen targetfile= regexs(0) if(regexm(`datafiles', "[A-Z][A-Z][H][R][0-9][0-9][A-Z][A-Z]"))
```

However, I would also appreciate a different approach.

Comment: The edit of the question suggests an even simpler answer: the wildcard `*hr*.dta` will catch all `.dta` files with `hr` in their names. The answers ranged more widely: either way, it is not clear why you appear to think the question remains open, in so far as you haven't accepted any answer. Nor have you explained why the answers aren't what you are looking for.

Comment: The answers solve my problem and I was just trying them out on my analysis to get the most suitable one.

Comment: OK, but what is wrong or inadequate about just using the right wildcard?

Comment: @nick Am not sure how to use the wildcard. `use *hr*.dta` does not seem to work. I must be missing something in the statement

Comment: `local datafiles : dir . files  "*hr*.dta"` selects your files, after which you loop doing whatever you want.

Comment: @nick Using the wildcard works and is indeed the most concise approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following Nick's advice to continue working with local macros rather than putting filenames into Stata variables, here is some technique to accomplish your stated objective. I agree with Nick to ignore the capitalization of the filenames provided by Windows, which is a case-insensitive filesystem. My example will work with case-sensitive filesystems, but will match any upper- or lower- or mixed-case filenames.

```
. dir *.dta

-rw-r--r--  1 lisowskiw  staff  1199 Jan 18 10:04 a space.dta
-rw-r--r--  1 lisowskiw  staff  1199 Jan 18 10:04 etbr41fl.dta
-rw-r--r--  1 lisowskiw  staff  1199 Jan 18 10:04 ethr41fl.dta
-rw-r--r--  1 lisowskiw  staff  1199 Jan 18 10:04 etir41fl.dta
-rw-r--r--  1 lisowskiw  staff  1199 Jan 18 10:04 etkr41fl.dta
-rw-r--r--  1 lisowskiw  staff  1199 Jan 18 10:04 etwi41fl.dta

. local datafiles : dir . files  "*.dta" 

. di `"`datafiles'"'
"a space.dta" "etbr41fl.dta" "ethr41fl.dta" "etir41fl.dta" "etkr41fl.dta" "etwi41fl.dta"

. foreach file of local datafiles {
  2.     display "`file' testing"
  3.         if regexm(upper("`file'"),"[A-Z][A-Z][H][R][0-9][0-9][A-Z][A-Z]") {
  4.             display "`file' matched!"
  5.             // process file here
.                 }
  6.         }
a space.dta testing
etbr41fl.dta testing
ethr41fl.dta testing
ethr41fl.dta matched!
etir41fl.dta testing
etkr41fl.dta testing
etwi41fl.dta testing
```

Comment: +1. This may well be what the OP is reaching towards, but if exact matching of names is the target, testing for equality should suffice!

Comment: The regular expression suggests the objective may actually be to find a filename containing HR followed by a 2-digit number, embedded between two pairs of letters.

Comment: Sounds plausible; if so, the opening sentence is a poor stab at the real question.

Comment: I agree. Sometimes the hardest part in solving a problem is figuring out what the problem really is. 10 years in academic-style computing support taught me never to take questions and assertions of problems at face value. :-)

Comment: @william Yes, the objective is to find a filename containing HR. I have edited the opening sentence for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filelist` (from SSC) to create a dataset of file names. You can then leverage the full set of Stata data management tools to identify the file you want to target. To install `filelist`, type in Stata's command window:

```
ssc install filelist
```

Here's a quick example with datasets that follow the example provided:

```
. filelist, norecur
Number of files found = 6

. list if strpos(upper(filename),".DTA")

     +---------------------------------+
     | dirname   filename        fsize |
     |---------------------------------|
  1. | .         ETBR41FL.dta   12,207 |
  2. | .         ETHR41FL.DTA   12,207 |
  3. | .         ETIR41FL.DTA   12,207 |
  4. | .         ETKR41FL.DTA   12,207 |
  5. | .         ETWI41FL.DTA   12,207 |
     +---------------------------------+

. keep if regexm(upper(filename), "[A-Z][A-Z][H][R][0-9][0-9][A-Z][A-Z]")
(5 observations deleted)

. list

     +---------------------------------+
     | dirname   filename        fsize |
     |---------------------------------|
  1. | .         ETHR41FL.DTA   12,207 |
     +---------------------------------+

. 
. * with only one observation in memory, use immediate macro expansion
. * to form the file name to read in memory
. use "`=filename'", clear
(1978 Automobile Data)

. describe, short

Contains data from ETHR41FL.DTA
  obs:            74                          1978 Automobile Data
 vars:            12                          18 Jan 2016 11:58
 size:         3,182                          
Sorted by: foreign
```

Comment: `filelist` works quite well. I can load the required data, but in my downstream analysis I need to merge the data set in memory with another data set (that needs to be searched for in the same way). However, if I run the `filelist` to search the 'merge using' data set, the memory is taken up by the small data set generated by `filelist`. With the other solution I can keep my main data set in memory and still search for the 'merge using' data set. I could however use a temp file to avoid 'losing' the master data set so again I say this is a great solution too

Answer (score 0):

I find the question very puzzling as it is about extracting a particular filename; but if you know the filename you want, you can just type it directly. You may need to revise your question if the point is different.

However, let's discuss some technique.

Putting Stata variable names inside Stata variables (meaning, strictly, columns in the dataset) is possible in principle, but it is only rarely the best idea. You should keep going in the direction you started, namely defining and then manipulating local macros.

In this case the variable element can be extracted by inspection, but let's show how to remove some common elements:

```
. local names etbr41fl.dta ethr41fl.dta etir41fl.dta etkr41fl.dta etwi41fl.dta

. local names : subinstr local names ".dta" "", all

. local names : subinstr local names "et" "", all

. di "`names'"
br41fl hr41fl ir41fl kr41fl wi41fl
```

That's enough to show more technique, which is that you can loop over such names. In fact with the construct you illustrate you can do that any way, and neither regular expressions nor anything else is needed:

```
. local datafiles : dir . files  "*.dta"

. foreach f of local datafiles { 
      ... using "`f'" 
} 

 . foreach n of local names { 
      ... using "et`n'.dta" 
 }
```

The examples here show a detail when giving literal strings, namely that `" "` are often needed as delimiters (and rarely harmful).

Note. Upper case and lower case in file names is probably irrelevant here. Stata will translate.

Note. You say that

```
. gen datafiles = "`datafiles'"
```

gives empty values. That's likely to be because you executed that statement in a locale where the local macro was invisible. Common examples are: executing one command from a do-file editor window and another from the main command window; executing commands one by one from a do-file editor window. That's why local macros are so named; they are **only** visible within the same block of code.

Comment: I had run commands in a block: `local datafiles : dir . files "*.dta"` `gen datafiles=`  `"\`datafiles'"` but gave empty new variable. But adding extra ticks (\`...\`) to the datafiles part works as @william above did. I have edited my question adding that I have several files and folders to work on so I need to automate the data importation. The switch from macro to variable is because `strupper` does not seem to work with a macro. But I realize now that lowercase is not an issue with windows.

Comment: Thanks for coming back, but the details here aren't clear. The statement you cite should work. `strupper()` and macros are compatible for examples like yours.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case you do not really need to use a regular expression.

The `strmatch()` function will do the job equally well:

```
local datafiles etbr41fl.dta ethr41fl.dta etir41fl.dta etkr41fl.dta etwi41fl.dta

foreach x of local datafiles {
    if strmatch(upper("`x'"), "*HR*") display "`x'"
}
ethr41fl.dta
```

The use of the `upper()` function is optional.